# Wrapping nested C++ function pointer calls in Cython

Tags: python, c++, cython

I am trying to wrap the [biteopt optimization algorithm](https://github.com/avaneev/biteopt) in Python using Cython for potential future inclusion in SciPy. I do not really understand C++ though, so I am having trouble compiling. This post is a bit long, so sorry in advance.

It boils down to wrapping the following functions from the header file (I am testing an older version of biteopt first):

```
typedef double (*biteopt_func)( int N, const double* x,
    void* func_data );

inline int biteopt_minimize( const int N, biteopt_func f, void* data,
    const double* lb, const double* ub, double* x, double* minf,
    const int iter, const int M = 1, const int attc = 10,
    const int stopc = 0 )
```

I tried to mimic how SciPy [wraps](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/main/scipy/optimize/tnc/_moduleTNC.pyx) the TNC optimizer written in C.

What I came up with so far is

```
from libc.string cimport memcpy
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython


np.import_array()

ctypedef np.float64_t float64_t

cdef extern from "biteopt.h":
    ctypedef double(*biteopt_func)(int, const double* [], void*)

    cdef int biteopt_minimize(const int n, biteopt_func function, void *add_data,
                              const double *lower_bounds[], const double *upper_bounds[],
                              double *x[], double *f, const int maxfun, const int depth,
                              const int attempts, const int stopping)  except *

cdef struct s_pybiteopt_state:
  void *py_function
  int n
  int failed
ctypedef s_pybiteopt_state pybiteopt_state


cdef double* function(int dim, const double *x[], void *state):
    # However, if the user function raises Exceptions Cython should deal
    # with it.

    cdef:
        pybiteopt_state *py_state
        int n
        double *x_data

    py_state = <pybiteopt_state *>state
    n = py_state.n

    if py_state.failed:
        # perhaps the objective function had an exception?
        raise ValueError("Error!")

    # ensures we're working on a copy of the data, just in case user function
    # mutates it
    xcopy = np.empty(n, dtype=np.float64)
    x_data = <float64_t *>np.PyArray_DATA(xcopy)
    memcpy(x_data, x, sizeof(double) * n)

    fx = (<object>py_state.py_function)(xcopy)

    if not np.isscalar(fx):
        try:
            fx = np.asarray(fx).item()
        except (TypeError, ValueError) as e:
            raise ValueError(
                "The user-provided objective function "
                "must return a scalar value."
            ) from e

    f = <double> fx

    return &f

cdef biteopt_func objective = &function

def minimize_biteopt(fun,
                     np.ndarray[np.float64_t] x0,
                     np.ndarray[np.float64_t] low,
                     np.ndarray[np.float64_t] up,
                     int maxfun,
                     int depth,
                     int attempts,
                     int stopping):

    cdef:
        pybiteopt_state py_state
        int n
        double f = np.inf
        double *x_data
        double *lower_bounds_data = NULL
        double *upper_bounds_data = NULL

    py_state.failed = 0

    n = low.size
    lower_bounds_data = <float64_t *>np.PyArray_DATA(low)
    upper_bounds_data = <float64_t *>np.PyArray_DATA(up)
    x = np.copy(x0, order="C")
    x_data = <float64_t *>np.PyArray_DATA(x)

    py_state.n = n
    py_state.py_function = <void*> fun

    res = biteopt_minimize(n, objective, NULL,
                           &lower_bounds_data, &upper_bounds_data,
                           &x_data, &f, maxfun, depth, attempts,
                           stopping)

    return res
```

This unfortunately results in

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...

    f = <double> fx

    return &f

cdef biteopt_func objective = &function
                             ^
------------------------------------------------------------

scipybiteopt/_modulebiteopt.pyx:66:30: Cannot assign type 'double *(*)(int, const double **, void *)' to 'biteopt_func'
```

I also tried out using `function` directly in `biteopt_minimize` which led to another compilation error.

I noticed that there are similar questions on SO, but none that helped me enough to figure it out.

Comment: The return types are different.

Comment: Depending on the version of Cython you're using the exception behaviour may also be different (`function` is assumed to be able to raise an exception, but the `biteopt_func` is to a function that can't raise an exceptions). You can fix this by adding `noexcept` to `function`. The next release of Cython should have improved error diagnostics to help you spot this, but right now it's a bit non-obvious if you don't know what you're looking for